# gs video, then kinect sketch in processing

Tags: java, processing, openni

Im trying to do a small project when the app run a video with the gsVideo library, and then run a kinect sketch, im making it in processing and Open NI, my knowledge in java is really limited.. so .. what could I do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Processing it's a lot easier to use the [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) wrapper rather than the Java wrapper that ships with the official OpenNI. Try running a SimpleOpenNI sample then modify it to play video via gsvideo.